# Total Count of each

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have a problem with my SQL Server query.

My query must display the total number of each category. Not the total amount of all categories.

```
SELECT [CATEGORY],
       (SELECT COUNT(*)  
        FROM [Group_New_DB].[dbo].[INCIDENTSM1] 
        WHERE ([OPEN_TIME] >=  @StartDate and [OPEN_TIME] < @EndDate + 1) ) AS OpenedCount, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)  
        FROM [Group_New_DB].[dbo].[INCIDENTSM1]
        WHERE ([CLOSE_TIME] >=  @StartDate and [CLOSE_TIME] < @EndDate + 1)) AS ClosedCount   
FROM [Group_New_DB].[dbo].[INCIDENTSM1] 
GROUP BY CATEGORY 
ORDER BY CATEGORY
```

The report consists of a table with 3 columns: Category, Registered, Closed.
1 column is the category name.
2 column is how many categories have been registered.
3 column -> how many columns were closed.
But result

The result that turned out as a result does not look right.

[image]

Comment: Is category a table or just field?

Comment: Category is a field.

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what is the difference between total number vs total amount as the question doesn't provide any context.

Although, if you are trying to get OpenedCount and ClosedCount as you have named the columns, I suggest you try below:

```
SELECT
    CATEGORY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (OPEN_TIME >= @start_date AND OPEN_TIME < @end_date+1) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
    END) AS OPENED_COUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (CLOSED_TIME >= @start_date AND CLOSED_TIME < @end_date+1) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
    END) AS CLOSED_COUNT
FROM
    [Group_New_DB].[dbo].[INCIDENTSM1]
GROUP BY
    CATEGORY
ORDER BY
    CATEGORY
```

IMO, This is also a better way as it doesn't include multiple sub-queries.

**Correction:** changed `COUNT` to `SUM` as suggested by TriV - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead -

```
SELECT [CATEGORY],
COUNT(CASE WHEN [OPEN_TIME] >=  @StartDate and [OPEN_TIME] < @EndDate + 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS OpenedCount, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN [CLOSE_TIME] >=  @StartDate and [CLOSE_TIME] < @EndDate + 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ClosedCount   
FROM [Group_New_DB].[dbo].[INCIDENTSM1] GROUP BY
CATEGORY ORDER BY CATEGORY
```